# how to set screen resolution for all screen in parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

How to set screen resolution for all screens like desktop, laptop, etc,. in parallax movement. 
I am currently working on a parallax website. I have a problem to set the screen resolution for all screens. I want to put several images in the background. The width of every image is 5212px.

Comment: any one can help me in this problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically?

Comment: Thanks todd. i want to give these three iamages in background in the parallax. On scrolling the images scrolling and when i goto ctrl+- on the browser these images also goto to zoom out..i want the images stay on there places..

Comment: So, [have you tried anything yet](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)? What is your site's structure? How do you achieve parallax scrolling? Also, include all additional information to your question, not your comments.

Comment: yeeeehhhhhhhhh a solve my problem..thats the way people say that I am The Best.....Thanks Zeta and Todd to reply me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the width of the images as a percentage rather than a width. If you set the width to 100% rather than 5212px for example then no matter how much you zoom in or out and resize the window the image will always be 100% of the window size.

Comment: yes i want like this..but how can i do this..this tell me inn details.